# How do I add autocompletion for a new language?

Tags: company-mode, auto-complete-mode

I have written code that returns lists of symbols representing modules and exported functions of a programming language. How do I integrate it with some autocompletion in Emacs?

I looked at company and completion-at-point-functions. I managed to run simple example successfully, and then I realised that all these examples use a predefined list of completion candidates.

Last code sample on the following page is a good example
http://sixty-north.com/blog/writing-the-simplest-emacs-company-mode-backend

I do not know what the completion candidates will be at this point. How do I create a dynamic list of candidates generated when I run M-x company-sample-backend?

Actually, the example at sixty-north.com can be easily modified to use dynamic completion. The problem lies elsewhere.

Replacing constant

```
(defconst sample-completions
  '("alan" "john" "ada" "don"))
```

with a function returning strings with random content and calling that function at the bottom of the backend function works.

In the end I have settled on following code:

```
(require 'company)

(defun company-lfe-backend (command &optional arg &rest ignored)
  (interactive (list 'interactive))

  (case command
    (interactive (company-begin-backend 'company-lfe-backend))
    ;; unfinished code related to major modes
    (prefix (and (or t
                     (eq major-mode 'fundamental-mode))
                 (company-grab-symbol)))
    (candidates
     (-map 'symbol-name
           (-flatten
            ;; following function returns the structure containing possible
            ;; auto completions
            (lfedoc-sexp-autocompletion-at-point))))))

(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-lfe-backend)
```

Comment: I looked at helm documentation, and I found an example that can generate a list of options and print it in the Messages buffer. However, I can't find a way to put it in the buffer I want.

Comment: Try looking at [`autocomplete`](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete) and [`company`](http://company-mode.github.io/).

Comment: https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/wiki/Writing-backends  the simple backend looks promising

Comment: This is another interesting tutorial, http://sixty-north.com/blog/writing-the-simplest-emacs-company-mode-backend

Comment: You can also locally bind completion-at-point-functions to custom functions to extend Emacs' built-in completion.

Comment: Slime seems to be a backend that does what I want. https://github.com/anwyn/slime-company/blob/master/slime-company.el